# Rules for writing database relationship

Tags: java, sql, database, annotations, relational-database

I have two table, the first table is article table,  and the second is author table. One author can write many articles,
I want to write the relation annotation `@ManyToOne`, which one correct `@ManyTone` `Article-Author` or `@ManyToOne` `Author-Article` ?

Comment: This is a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. If you do have a code question please give a [mre]. Show parts you can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said:

> One author can write many articles

This would translate as ManyToOne Article-Author, in other words: many articles to one author.

Answer (score 1):

To simply say you have the following relationship :

- an `Author` produces many `Articles`
- one or many `Articles` are produces by one `Author`

In your entities you will have the following annotations :

- for `Author` `@OneToMany`
- for `Article` `@ManyToOne`